# Apache2, mpm_event + PHP-FPM Error logs on same line

Tags: php, logging, apache2, fpm

I upgraded my Debian7 to Debian10 yesterday, and changed from prefork to mpm_event with php-fpm (php 7.4)

The error messages and error_log output, is shown in my /apache/error.log file as: 
I've replaced filenames, ip and port.

`[Tue May 19 11:26:38.506805 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 28334:tid 139811391133440] [client (ip):(port)] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: SQL_ERROR in (file) on line 198PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: SQL_ERROR in (file) on line 200PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: SQL_ERROR_MSG in (file) on line 201PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: SQL_command in (file) on line 202'`

And all errors are buffered, and output on the same line (quite difficult to debug).

php-fpm uses www-data user

error.log has 640 permissions with www-data:www-data

php-fpm/pool.d/www.conf got the error.log = /var/log/apache2/error.log

Do you have any suggestions, as to why i'm not getting the error logs directly in the error.log file?

**Edit**: All PHP configs is from a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same system as you, Debian 10, php-fpm 7.3 (instead of 7.4), apache2 and had the same issue with a messy output.

I solved it with a small script, manually adding the new line character \n and also a tab \t for pretty printing

```
#!/bin/sh
tail -f "/var/log/apache2/$1" | sed 's/PHP\s/\n\tPHP\s/g'
```

Now I see each message on a new line, with a simple indentation as well. You can give the script any name, I choosed greplog, placed on system path with enough permissions, and pass the log filename as parameter

Comment: I actually ended up setting the apache log, as the php-fpm error output log. I still get the "ugly" oneliner, but all the php-fpm errors, are neatly on each line. 

So basically i just ignore the last one-liner.

Comment: My custom filter: `| sed -e "s/\\\\n/\\n/g" -e "s/PHP message: /\\n/g"`

Answer (score -1):

When upgrading from Debian 7 to Debian 10 your version of PHP was probably upgraded from 5.4 to 7.4.

PHP 7 has many breaking changes so I'm guessing that your code is using some of the features that were removed / hits syntatical changes introduced.

See here for the debian php version matrix:
https://wiki.debian.org/PHP

And here for PHP breaking changes:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php

Comment: Hi nover, thanks for your reply.

I installed PHP and all configs from scratch, so there shouldn't be any 5.6-stuff left. I forgot to mention that :)

Comment: Exactly my point - you moved from php 5.6 to 7.x? Did you ensure to check all your php scripts for 7.x compatibility?In the migration guide there is a section called `Calls from incompatible context removed` which shows some "undefined variable" outputs. Could be your problem :)

Comment: Hello :)

I've tried with an "empty" file. just echoing "test" from the error_log, and the result is the same. It's being directed through the "syslogger" (i think?), instead of going directly to the error log file